# Shuffle Multiple Lists With The Same Order Using Command Prompt

Tags: list, shuffle

I need to shuffle multiple lists from text files so that their shuffle orders are consistent:

Input:

```
List 1 = 1,2,3,4,5
List 2 = 5,4,8,7,9
```

Expected output:

```
List 1: 2,3,4,1,5
List 2: 4,8,7,5,9
```

How can I do this using command prompt?

Thanks and appreciate it.